# Image manipulation in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am showing one image over the other in an ImageView. I want the user to be able to rotate and zoom the above image while the bottom image remains as it is. I've tried BitmapDrawable and Matrix classes but these are rotating only one image. I am unable to figure out, how to rotate only image. Please guide me, how could I achive the above.

Comment: can u share ur xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webview over your imageview, this will give you the zooming features, plus you can write a simple JS func to rotate your image. This way, there will be no change in the position of the image which at bottom and you will be able to do all the things that you wanted on the upper image.